# move object from list a to list b in C#

Tags: c#, list, move

I am trying to create a random list that will be random each time the user opens the page. The random list will also be larger than the original list (where the objects are coming from) and will contain duplicates.

I cannot seem to find the right way to move an object from list A to list B based on a randomized index to pull from:

```
Grappling2 = new List<Grappling2>
            {
                new Grappling2
                {
                    ImageT = "HemaSwordFiore.Images.BGGrapple.IronGate.png",
                    TrainingText = "Iron Gate"
                },
                new Grappling2
                {
                    ImageT = "HemaSwordFiore.Images.BGGrapple.IronGate.png",
                    TrainingText = "Long guard"
                }
            }

TempListGrappling2 = new List<TempListGrappling2>();//empty list
                    
                var rand = new Random();
                ndx = rand.Next(3);
    
                for (int counter = 0; counter < 6; counter++)
                {
                    ndx++;
                    TempListGrappling2.Add(new Grappling2[ndx]);
                }
      }
```

This obviously gives me an error since I cannot convert Grappling2[] to TempListGrappling2. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where is TempListGrappling2 defined? Where is your other list defined? What is your error? Please edit your post with this info.

Comment: the error is "CS1503: cannot convert Grappling2[] to TempListGrappling2". The list definitions are set on my contentpage (and the lists work)

Comment: Please add the definitions to your question. There's no way to help you with the current information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are asking for something along the lines of this:

```
        // the source list
        List<int> first = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
  
        // the list to copy into
        List<int> second = new List<int>();

        var rand = new Random();

        // how many items we will insert into the second list
        int count = rand.Next(first.Count, int.MaxValue);

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            // a random index from the source list
            int index = rand.Next(0, first.Count);

            // add that source value to our second list
            second.Add(first[index]);
        }
```

Note, the `List` is holding `int` here, but you may be working with a different data type.

With your code in mind, it could look something like this:

```
        List<Grappling2> Grappling2 = new List<Grappling2>()  {
                new Grappling2
                {
                    ImageT = "HemaSwordFiore.Images.BGGrapple.IronGate.png",
                    TrainingText = "Iron Gate"
                },
                new Grappling2
                {
                    ImageT = "HemaSwordFiore.Images.BGGrapple.IronGate.png",
                    TrainingText = "Long guard"
                }
            };
        List<Grappling2> TempListGrappling2 = new List<Grappling2>();

        var rand = new Random();
        int count = rand.Next(Grappling2.Count, int.MaxValue);

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            int index = rand.Next(0, Grappling2.Count);
            TempListGrappling2.Add(Grappling2[index]);
        }
```